# No Scope Defined In Commentmodule For Commentable Model Request

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using the [comment-model](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/comment-module/) I setting up as the instruction. After setting up, I got this error

> No scope defined in CommentModule for commentable Model Request

I'm using rights and user module in my application. I changed  'userModelClass'=>'User', to 'userModelClass'=>'Users',only at the config/main.php. What am I wrong? Do I need to create new model for comment_tbl at the protected/models?

Comment: userModelClass should be 'User' and have you created "Create a database table for every commentable Model relation". can you paste your code what you tried it help us to debug your issue ?

Comment: Thank Rajat, I did it by myself by ajax.

Comment: @tharsoe - can you please share your solution by ajax? I'm facing the same problem :( Or 2 years are too much? :D